# Function that ensures html start and end tags are correct

Tags: scala

I have a form where users enter some simple html tags, and I want to parse their text to ensure the following:

**All start tag's have a matching end tag**

It is a simplified markup for end users, not too strict.

So these would pass:

```
<text>hello world<text>
<text>hello world</text>
<123>
```

And this would fail:

```
<hello> ><
```

So it isn't strict html as you can see from the first example, it basically just ensures there is a the same number of open and close brackets, and that they appear in the correct order i.e. you can't begin with a close bracket and then have an end bracket.

Answer (score 0):

This is a different question, but a very similar function to the one being worked with in [Scala way to program bunch of if's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12523788/scala-way-to-program-bunch-of-ifs/12524043) See the top answers in that question, however, the "state" you'll be passing around won't be "how many open's have we had" but a boolean for "inside or outside?"

Answer (score 0):

You need a stack data structure. Basically you read the input and every time you encounter opening tag, you push onto the stack. When you encounter ending tag, you pop last item from the stack and compare them. They should always be equal. At the end the stack should be empty.

If you want to check whether braces are correct, the algorithm is slightly different. When closing bracket is encountered, pop the top of the stack and it must be an opening bracket.

Answer (score 0):

Could use regex if it's just lines with a single start and end tag.

```
"<head>abc</head>"  matches """<([^<>]+)>[^<>]*</\1>""" // true
"<head>abc</head>>" matches """<([^<>]+)>[^<>]*</\1>""" // false
"<head>abc</hed>"   matches """<([^<>]+)>[^<>]*</\1>""" // false
"<head>abc<head>"   matches """<([^<>]+)>[^<>]*</\1>""" // false
```