# Scala List[Char] is empty but does not return true

Tags: scala, recursion

I have the following piece of code (this is for my coursea assignment)

```
def balance(chars: List[Char]): Boolean = {
  def innerBalance(chars: List[Char], count: Int): Boolean = {
    if (chars.isEmpty) count == 0
    if (chars.head == '(') innerBalance(chars.tail, count+1)
    if (chars.head == ')') (count > 0) && innerBalance(chars.tail, count-1)
    innerBalance(chars.tail, count)
  }

  innerBalance(chars, 0)
}
```

From what I can tell, it's very similar to the stew's answer on this [Scala way to program bunch of if's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12523788/scala-way-to-program-bunch-of-ifs)
but I don't know why the statement

```
if (chars.isEmpty) count == 0
```

always be false.

If I run a test like this

```
balance("".toList)
```

it just throws exception.

Thanks for your help.
Regards,

Comment: this is not a very idiomatic use of scala. I'd advice for use to use `match` to reduce verbosity and the complexity of your solution.

Answer (score 4):

In Scala you never should use `return`, but instead write expressions. The main issue with the code above is that you are not using `if` expressions, i.e. you have omitted the `else` part and therefore the compiler is inferring `Unit` (Java's void, which means that "nothing" gets returned).

As there are multiple alternatives in your case, I suggest you use a match expression:

```
chars match {
  case '(' :: Nil => ...
  case ')' :: Nil => ...
  case Nil        => count == 0
  case _          => innerBalance(chars.tail, count)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Adding to [Huw's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15870309/367649), You can also use pattern matching to make it more elegant:

```
      def innerBalance(chars: List[Char], count: Int): Boolean = chars match {
          case _ if count < 0  => false
          case Nil             => count == 0
          case '(' :: rest     => innerBalance(rest, count + 1)
          case ')' :: rest     => innerBalance(rest, count - 1)
          case _ :: rest       => innerBalance(rest, count)
      }
```

Comment: They actually cannot (pattern matching will be introduced only next week after this Scala Course assignment).

Comment: There's no rule against using things that haven't been covered.

Answer (score 0):

A block like

```
{
  if (a) b
  c
}
```

will do `b` if `a` is true, and then *always* do `c`. If you want `c` to happen only when `a` is false, you need to use `else`:

```
{
  if (a) b
  else c
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that helps. I need to explicitly add "return" keyword for each of my statements. Just realized the my problem right after posting the question.